# Accessing the query string in a document

Tags: php, javascript, url

How can I place the value of a variable from the URL query string (e.g., `?location=london`) into an HTML page?

I currently have been trying to do this and implemented a url parser and placed it inside the html page with this

```
<span id="location"></span>
```

near the area that I want it to belong, unfortunately this didn't seem to work.

Comment: <?php echo $_GET['location'];  ?> should be all you need, assuming the page is parsing php

Comment: What about in terms of placing within html code though? Do I just place that above and then it should be able to use the span?

Comment: you place it exactly where you want the word from the url to appear.

Comment: Dagon, thank-you for your patience and kind help :) Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you need.

```
   echo $_GET['location'];
```

Comment: You need to sanitize this input. A malicious person could offer a link to your site that has evil code in the "location" variable.

Comment: ::Rolls eyes:: Yes, malicious input is a problem, but he didn't ask about that.  Also, if you are going to treat this code snip as a full program and critique it as that then all that would happen is it would print the malicious code on the screen.  Unless you know of a vulnerability in the echo language construct that would execute the code in the get variable instead of print it...otherwise what you're saying sounds like you misunderstand these attacks.

Comment: @k Here's the kinds of attacks I'm talking about. [Example](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/xss-attack-examples/)